# How do we retrieve all keys along with their prefixes from a JSON document

Tags: java, json, mongodb

```
{
    "empId":"1",
    "name":"Alex",
    "role":"president",
    "phone":"123",
    "address": {
        "street":"xyz",
        "city":"hyd",
        "pincode":400123
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve keys as following so that I can allow the user to choose such keys in the UI.

```
keys: ["empId","name","role","phone", "address", "address.street", "address.city", 
"address.pincode"]
```

The same can be used for querying on Mongo directly. I tried using JSONObject and get keys but I am unable to fetch documents along with the path they come from.

Please let me know if there's a direct way I can use in Java or if Mongo has a way to get all keys from where they are coming

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using recursion.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String str = "{ \"empId\":\"1\", \"name\":\"Alex\", \"role\":\"president\", \"phone\":\"123\", \"address\": { \"street\":\"xyz\", \"city\":\"hyd\", \"pincode\":400123 }}";
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(str);
    List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
    recLevels(keysList, obj, "");
    System.out.println(keysList);
}

public static void recLevels(List<String> keysList, JSONObject obj, String prefix) {
    Set<String> keys = (Set<String>) obj.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        keysList.add(prefix + (prefix.isEmpty() ? "" : ".") + key);
        if (obj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            recLevels(keysList, (JSONObject) obj.get(key), prefix + (prefix.isEmpty() ? "" : ".") + key);
        }
    }
}
```

What the `recLevels` method does is to go through all the keys of an object and check is any of these keys has an object as its value `if (obj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject)`, if it does `recLevels` is called again for that object and the process is repeated for that object (one level down).

The important part here is the `prefix` variable which is used to store the previous keys on the previous levels.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying for recursion only but I couldn't assign the proper prefix  while calling the method recursively. It was going wrong there

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional array and push all keys in that array.

Use `JSON.Stringyfy` function to present it as string to end user.

```
var keys = [],

sourceArray = [{
    "empId":"1",
    "name":"Alex",
    "role":"president",
    "phone":"123",
    "address": {
        "street":"xyz",
        "city":"hyd",
        "pincode":400123
    }
}]; //Test data

$.each(sourceArray, function(k, v) {
    //k is the key and v is the value (key-value pair)
    keys.push(k);
});

//You have all the keys - use at your disposal
```

Note: I've not tested this code in absence of source-code, please validate and modify as per your actual code.

Comment: I am able to fetch all keys directly even from nested JSON objects as well but I would like to keep a track of their parent keys as well.   For eg:  {"a":"aval", "b":"bval", "c" : {"d": "dval", "e":"eval"}, I want the keys to be [a,b, c, c.d, c.e] instead of  [a,b,c,d,e]